# Ionic 3 TypeError: this.http.post is not a function in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3

I have call the POST in ionic 3.0 and i got error this.http.post is no a function in the console i try this link for resolve this error : [Ionic 3 TypeError: this.http.post is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064698/ionic-3-typeerror-this-http-post-is-not-a-function) but its not working for me please tell me anyone how to fix this error ?

```js
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    
  //Pass the data into the API and creat the user
    if(url != "" && url != undefined){
      this.http.post(url, object, options).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "bob-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.2.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "bob-app"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

CreatAccount.ts

```
import { HttpModule,Headers,RequestOptions}        from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

//app.module.ts
import { HttpModule}       from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: Which http module are you using? which provider did you inject? also which is the angular version

Comment: Sir check my updated fiddle

Comment: Remove imports related to HttpModule .. its deprecated. Use HttpClient and HttpClientModule

Comment: Sir i use both but after API call  i got "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"  from the response message?

Comment: That is progress for you.. that implies some sort of server side error.. you can try testing your api using a rest client

Comment: ok sir thanks  this information are very important for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166458/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-suraj-rao).

Answer (score 2):

Http and HttpModule are deprecated.

Remove those imports.

Import `HttpClientModule` in the app module or page module as required and set into imports array.

Inject in constructor as below:

```
constructor(http:HttpClient){}
```

in the required provider.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

//app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule}       from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

**replace**

```
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
```

In CreatAccount.ts

```
import { HttpModule,Headers,RequestOptions}        from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

**replace**

```
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
```

and then change

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

**To**

```
headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

 Then write a function 

postObject(){

  if(url != "" && url != undefined){
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.http.post(url, object,
              {headers: this.header})
              .subscribe(
                data => {
                  console.log(data['_body']);

                },
                err => {

                  console.log(err);}
              );
          })
  }
}
```

Comment: sir i got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined after use this?

Comment: how is this related to the original error? Can you explain how wrapping in a promise will solve it?

Comment: make sure platform inject in constructor

Comment: no.. httpCLient is not a cordova plugin.. it wont matter

Comment: please check it Suraj Rao bro

Comment: Make sure to atleast try to understand the issue and test your code instead of being the _first answer_ here

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you have:

// app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

...
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
...
```

// page.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {      
    }

postData() {
   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });      
   //Pass the data into the API and create the user
   if(url != "" && url != undefined){
       this.http.post(url, object, options).subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
           console.log(error);
       });
    }
}
```

If you forget to add the HttpClient to your constructor, you will not get very far.

Hope this helps.